# Split View Controller delegate and toolBar button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using the normal delegate methods to display a button in portrait mode to show/hide the `UITableView` in this way:

I'm using this in the `UITableViewController`:

```
 // Split View Controller
 - (void)awakeFromNib
 {
     [super awakeFromNib];
     self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
 }

 - (id <SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter>)splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter
{
    id detailVC = [self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    if (![detailVC conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SplitViewBarButtonItemPresenter)]) {
        detailVC = nil;
    }
    return detailVC;
}

- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
   shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
              inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation);
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
          withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
       forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    barButtonItem.title = @"Table of Data";
    [self splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter].splitViewBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
     willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController
  invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    [self splitViewBarButtonItemPresenter].splitViewBarButtonItem = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

While in my `DetailViewControllerS` (multiple) i'm using

```
- (void)handleSplitViewBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)splitViewBarButtonItem
{
    NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    if (_splitViewBarButtonItem) [toolbarItems removeObject:_splitViewBarButtonItem];
    if (splitViewBarButtonItem) [toolbarItems insertObject:splitViewBarButtonItem atIndex:0];
    self.toolbar.items = toolbarItems;
    _splitViewBarButtonItem = splitViewBarButtonItem;
}

- (void)setSplitViewBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)splitViewBarButtonItem
{
    if (splitViewBarButtonItem != _splitViewBarButtonItem) {
        [self handleSplitViewBarButtonItem:splitViewBarButtonItem];
    }
}
```

The problem is if change the detail view through a "Replace Segue" the button to show/hide the `UITableView` in the new `DetailViewController` disappears unless i rotate the iPad to landscape and then back to portrait!
Or even if i go to a another `ViewController`, which should not present the button, and then go back to my main `DetailView` the button is not shown unless i rotate the device.
How can i fix it, making the button always appear if i'm in portrait mode??

Answer (score 0):

normally you shouldn't use replace segue in this case.

Those delegate methods plus a NavigationViewController are enough for displaying the barbutton item.